# Azure Data Factory: Different Compute environment

Tags: azure-data-factory

There are couple of compute environments that can do transformations for me. I have a REST source from where I am getting responses every day and I have to perform some transformations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/compute-linked-services

I am confused as to what could be the best way to do it? Or in other words whats the different between all the compute environments as in when should I use Azure Batch, stored procedures, HDInsight, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on where you have the data. If you are storing the data in a data lake, you won't use a stored procedure. If you are storing the data in an Azure Sql, you won't use Data Lake Analytics.

Basically its like this:

```
Data lake -> data lake analytics with u-sql
Azure SQL (warehouse or just sql) -> stored procedure
HDInsight hadoop -> Pig, hive, etc
None of the above -> custom activity with Azure Batch
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Ok so my transformed data will be at Azure sql warehouse. Now can i not use HDInsight for transformation? Like is it possible in anyway to use it?

Comment: and since tranformed data will be at azure sql, how should i implement machine learning on it? Like HDInsight should I use (spark) or data lake analytics or custom activity? and how can the data of azure sql be used in HDInsight environment?

Comment: basically I want to move away from stored procedure because from what i believe it takes a lot of time in transformation as compared to Spark. And if you ask me, azure factory documentation are not that clear on many things.

Comment: I recommend reading more through the documentation and coming with more specific questions, I can assure you that the answers you need are in the official documentation, and better explained than what I can type here :)

Comment: Ya. Since I have read a bit of documentation during the weekend, now the above questions looks absurd to me. ;) Surely I will read the documentation more thoroughly now.